# why wont function which pushes text from multiple files (uploaded using html5 file reader) return the array

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am trying to upload two text files using the html 5 file reader. I can get the files into an array okay but cant return the array from the function.  I guess I could just push them into a global array and work with that. However my main reason for asking this question is to learn why the return doesn't work as there is obviously something I don't understand here.

```
function processFiles(files) {
    console.log(getEmails(files));   //this statement should log textArray to console, but returns undefined instead
    function getEmails(files){
        var textArray = [];

        for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            (function(files,i){

                var file = files[i];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    textArray.push(e.target.result);
                    if (i==(files.length-1))
                    {
                        console.log(textArray); //this logs test array to the console no probs
                        return textArray;// so why wont this return text array so the previous console.log works
                    }
                };  
                reader.readAsText(file,"Unicode");  
            })(files,i);

        }
    } 
}


<input id="fileInput" type="file" onchange="processFiles(this.files)" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set reader.onload, you're not calling the function, you're indicating a function to be called when the file is loaded.  This will happen at some point in the future, not within the context of your getEmails function.  This is called an asynchronous function.

You won't ever be able to log those files (if you want to log when they are loaded) in processFiles.  You need an external function called for each "onload" event that will build up the textArray (which, generally, should be a global variable), know when a total of "i" files have loaded (again, this should be tracked globally;  and note that you don't know in what order this will happen), and then log the result.

(I'm also not sure why, within the loop, you wrap the functionality in another function.  That stuff can all be in-line in the loop.)

You may want to read up on asynchronous processing to get a clearer idea of what's going on.